# Сборка apk из Android-приложения

Tags: java, android

я делаю что-то типа приложения, с помощью которого можно написать приложение.

Каким образом можно запустить процесс сборки апк, если есть папка с исходным кодом? Нашёл кое-какой сайт: https://annimon.com/article/2140
там вроде какие-то ссылки, да и код дан, но.. всё же я ничего не понял)

P.S.
Процесс сборки apk нужно запустить с самого устройства андроид, т.е. внутри самого приложения

Comment: у вас Android Studio?

Comment: да (нужны ещё символы)

Comment: в смысле символы?

Comment: чтобы комментарий отправить, нужно 15 символов

Comment: исправьте вопрос, не до конца понятно было

Comment: В той статье все и описано. Сделаете свой toolset (стандартного не существует) и сможете собирать.